# seeking workaround for animated gif frame limit

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I was attempting to render a **514** frame png sequence as an animated .gif from *Photoshop*. It imported fine, but I discovered that within the `Save for web...` dialog, there is a **500** frame limit.

There's an [unanswered question on the Adobe Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/792760) about this from years ago. Other tidbits online state there is no limit to frames for the animated gif format.

Is there an Adobe-centric workaround? Perhaps either *Photoshop* or *Media Encoder*.  Thanks!

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: There is much more in life than Adobe. Take a look at virtual Dub 2. It is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a thing with Photoshop for a long and hairy time - the 500 frame `.gif` limit is hard-baked into the way PS handles these files... there are workarounds, and cludges.

You might consider looking at other software / tools to accomplish your task: AfterEffects, Final Cut, heck even QuickTime & put your output out there as `.mp4` video file and use EZGIF to convert... for documentation of processes on Windows boxes I often use Screen2GIF, and that has some pretty great tools for GIF building, optimization etc, and has no frame limits.

Hope this helps.